# jQuery add class .active on menu within subfolders

Tags: jquery, css, addclass

I was able to find a solid solution on how to add an 'active' class to menu items based on the url of the page:

```
jQuery(function(){
    var page = window.location.pathname,
        find = new RegExp(page == '/' ? window.location.origin + '/?jQuery' : page.replace(/\/jQuery/,''));
    jQuery('nav a').each(function(){
        if(find.test(this.href.replace(/\/jQuery/,''))){
            jQuery(this).addClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

This, however, does not work with links within subfolders and I can't seem to figure out a way to make it work. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I use and it works for menu items in my subfolders

```
$(".menu-item").each(function() {
  if (this.href == window.location.href) {
    $(this).addClass("active");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(jQuery){
        var url = window.location.href;
            jQuery('#nav a.level-top').filter(function() {
                return this.href == url;
        }).addClass('active');
        jQuery('#nav a.active').closest('li').addClass('active');
    });
```

Comment: Please elaborate your answer too.

Comment: @JohnRPerry This work for me...
here, var url = get the url from the browsers address bar and after that it filter with the #nav section's anchor tag which have level-top class url and assign active class afterward it also assign the active class to closest li or parent li active class